# Delete object from entity with relation one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I get `request` from db by Id : `Request originalRequest = RequestRepository.GetById(id);`

Then I get users id's from request comments :

```
var origRecipientsIds = originalRequest.Comments.Select(c => c.User.Id).ToList();
```

and from input model I receive new user (ids)

```
 var editedRecipientsIds = model.Recipients.ToList();
```

And then Remove comments by user Ids:

```
var recipientsIdToRemove = origRecipientsIds.Where(x => !editedRecipientsIds.Contains(x));
var recipientsToRemove = GetRecipientsToRemove(originalRequest, recipientsIdToRemove);
recipientsToRemove.ToList().ForEach(x => originalRequest.Comments.Remove(x));
```

`GetRecipientsToRemove` method returns collection of `RequestComment`'s

```
private IEnumerable<RequestComment> GetRecipientsToRemove(Request originalRequest,
            IEnumerable<int> recipientsIdsToRemove)
        {
            var recipientsToRemove = new List<RequestComment>();
            foreach (var id in recipientsIdsToRemove)
            {
                int localId = id;
                var origComment = originalRequest.Comments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User.Id == localId);
                if (!recipientsToRemove.Contains(origComment))
                {
                    recipientsToRemove.Add(origComment);
                }
            }
            return recipientsToRemove;
        }
```

After all of that I call `SaveChanges` method

```
RequestRepository.Context.Entry(originalRequest).State = EntityState.Modified;
            RequestRepository.SaveChanges();
```

and get Error

> The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Entity `RequestComment` has Non-Nullable FK to `Request`

```
public class RequestComment : IIdent
    {
        [ForeignKey("Request")]
        public int RequestId { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

---

I've tried to get again `requestComment` from db, mark it as `Deleted` and `Save`, but this doesn't help.

```
var dbComment = RequestCommentRepository.FindFirstOrDefault(x => x.User.Id == localId
                                                                           && x.RequestId == originalRequest.Id);
RequestCommentRepository.Context.Entry(dbComment ).State = EntityState.Deleted;
RequestCommentRepository.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Change `public int RequestId { get; set; }` to `public int? RequestId { get; set; }`. Also set the delete behavior to `Cascade` so the EF will delete the related entries in the other tables.

Comment: @flechilla, thanks for your comment. but is there any other solution that don't require changing entity?

Comment: Did you tried changing the delete behavior in the context to Cascade. EF should take care of that for you. If not you should delete first the related rows of what you one to delete in the other tables.

Comment: @flechilla : I don't understand why in this case i should take care about Cascade deleting. I delete only one comment that is related to not-deleted request. If I delete request, than yes, I should delete all comments and I need Cascade delete...

Comment: Ohh I see now. I haven't completly realize what you were trying to do. In that case the Cascade delete doesn't have sense.

Comment: @flechilla, for now I've made update that you have suggested to make property nullable and it works, but I don't know if I can do this so still try to find solution without changing entity. Thanks

Comment: Why do you say that you don't know if you can't do this? What do you mean with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111552/discussion-between-demo-and-flechilla).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a foreign key relationship between entities in your backing DBMS that you aren't resolving before deleting recipient entities. It's possibly between comment instances and recipient instances.

Make sure you understand which way your database's dependencies go. Delete the independent instances first.

Comment: Independent entity is `RequestComment`. Here is some prove I think http://imageshack.com/i/pl3FnH2vp (screenshot off db dependencies)

Comment: You mentioned `GetRecipientsToRemove` returns `Comment` instances, but it's returning `RequestComment` instances. Are `RequestComment` and `Comment` different entities? Does `Comment` even exist?

Comment: `Comment ` is `RequestComment ` my bad than